# css:change between two images while hovering

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm tring to change between two images in this site

- section "who we are" : I'm tring to make the background of the circle blue and the icon white(I got the white image also).

I tried to hide the first image and also to undisplay it...but whenever I do it, the second images won't show up...someone told me there is a little bit problem because the image is a background-image...

glad if someone could help me:)

there is the code:

```html
    <div class="aio-icon-img " style="font-size: 48px; border: 1px solid rgb(183, 183, 183); padding: 17px; border-radius: 100px; display: inline-block; top: -84px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <img class="img-icon" alt="" src="http://www.easy-send.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/NewIcon_Build_3.png">
    </div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these icons and do an image swap

[image]
[image]
[image]

e.g.

```
<img src="http://yourwebsitewebsite.com/images/NewBuild3.png"  
onMouseOver="this.src='http://www.yourwebsite.com/images/NewBuild3_hover.png'
onMouseOut="this.src='http://www.yourwebsite.com/images/NewBuild3.png'" />
```

Comment: that image swap is not exact but its off the top of my head

Comment: happy to help :) thank god for photoshop!!